# How to set up fingerprint unlock on Honor 6A?

Tags: lock-screens, 7.0-nougat, fingerprint, huawei-honor-6

Could please someone name the exact checkboxes I need (not) to tick on Honor 6A to have it unlock with my fingerprint? Fingerprint is configured and recognized in the settings, but the phone keeps asking for PIN every time.

Comment: Are you using another lockscreen application?

Comment: While I don't have the device, but basing on existing knowledge on lock screen options: do you use storage encryption? What lock screen options are available to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically you have to set up a pin (or password) before you can enable
>   fingerprints on the device, and you will be always required to enter
>   the pin/password when you first boot or the first time you log into a
>   protected user account.

After that point, if you have the fingerprint enabled for unlocking, you can use the fingerprint to directly wake and log in **if you are using the default lock screen**.

Many users have observed that  if you have installed anything that overrides the lock screen, this will stop working, and you will need to use the PIN again.

References

- [Use fingerprint to wake screen without PIN?](https://forum.xda-developers.com/mate-9/help/fingerprint-to-wake-screen-pin-t3546623)

Comment: Thank you very much for the enlightening link. I did have a 3rd party screen lock application active. Now that I removed it, my phone unlocks with a fingerprint as it should.

Comment: Anytime! I am glad you resolved the issue